# Protractor: How to get the baseUrl passed from the command line?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm looking for a way to get access to the baseUrl I've passed via the command line. Eg.

```
protractor conf.js --baseUrl=http://myawesomesite.com
```

I've tried `browser.baseUrl` returns me the `baseUrl` set in my `conf.js`, but seemingly not the one passed from the command line.

Comment: How about `browser.params.baseUrl`?

Comment: Or, `browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) { console.log(config.baseUrl); });`?

Comment: Nice ideas alecxe... sadly both displayed the same results.

Comment: can you share conf.js part which contains this param?

Comment: A quick check, what if comment out the `baseUrl` from your config and pass it via command-line. Do you see it in the `browser.baseUrl` in this case?

Comment: Yeah, Alecxe, I tried that too... in which case it's blank. Totally weird.

Comment: Based on the answers thus far, it looks like some folks are misunderstanding my question. To clarify, I am passing base url via the command line. I would like to access THAT baseUrl in my test (not the default one in the config). Hope that helps clarify :)

Comment: It looks like this might be a browserstack bug, as browser.baseUrl is working locally, but not on browserstack runs... sigh.

Answer (score 3):

`browser.baseUrl` IS the way to get the baseUrl...

The reason I thought there might be a different way to get the command line baseUrl, was because my tests were failing on browserstack. It was either ignoring the baseUrl passed from the command line, and using the default in the config. Removing the default in the config, then failed because it was blank.

Not sure what the solution for this is... **because it just started working again**. Could have been caching (though I don't know where), or perhaps Jasmine2 (since the issue was called in a BeforeAll block)?

Anyway, wanted to update this and thank the answerers for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Use-    `protractor conf.js --baseUrl http://myawesomesite.com`

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your conf.js, but if you have somehting like this:

```
params: {
        screenWidth: 1920,
        screenHeight: 1080,
    }
```

In this case it should be done this way:

```
protractor conf.js --params.screenWidth=1024
```